# oracle execution order in case condition in sql core

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Why does the following code not work in SQL?
In pl/sql, it works correctly (after minor code edits) .
According to the correct one, it should stop at checking  oopname = 'PAY_OPERDATE'
and not proceed to converting to a number to_number(substr(paramvalue,4,2))<=12.
Tested on the oracle up to 19c.

```
with data as(
select null oopname, 'fgdfhdfhdf' paramvalue from dual
)
select 
  case 
    when  oopname = 'PAY_OPERDATE' 
      and length(paramvalue)=10 
      and to_number(substr(paramvalue,4,2))<=12 
    then paramvalue 
  end
from data
```

In PostgreSQL code works correctly

```
select case when oopname = 'PAY_OPERDATE'  and length(paramvalue)=10 
and TO_NUMBER(substr(paramvalue,4,2),'99') <= 12
then paramvalue end aa
from (
select ''::text oopname, '02.hh.2022y'::text paramvalue 
) a
```

I want to get a technical explanation.
The documentation does not say how CONDITION is executed.
Very similar to a bug.

Comment: The question should actually be about why `oopname = 'PAY_OPERDATE' and length(paramvalue)=10 and to_number(substr(paramvalue,4,2))<=12` is not evaluated in the order it is written. In Oracle, wrapping it in a `CASE` expression is probably irrelevant to the question (however, if you are comparing to PostgreSQL and if that were to have inconsistent behaviour in the order expressions are evaluated between a `WHERE` clause and in a `CASE` expression then the comparison may be relevant).

Comment: It seems like oracle [offers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) short-circuit only for simple case expressions. Since yours is not, the order of operations is not guaranteed.

Comment: @markalex As I mention in the previous comment, the `CASE` expression is probably a distraction in this instance as the order of execution of the `WHEN` clauses is irrelevant (and the OP only has a single `WHEN` clause). What is relevant is the order of execution of the expressions in the composite expression that the `WHEN` clause is evaluating and the surrounding `CASE` expression would only be relevant if it forced a different method to evaluating expressions than for any other point in the syntax.

Comment: Agree with MT0. Artem, the key takeaway is that Oracle does not employ any (guaranteed) short-circuit evaluation. You have to assume all your clauses will be evaluated in any order Oracle deems appropriate. You can control order of execution in PL/SQL, not (easily) in SQL because of it's higher level nature (SQL describes what you want, it isn't programming code... Oracle writes the program [execution plan] for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, this is a semi bug.

All because of opname = 'PAY_OPERDATE'.
oopname in the example is NULL,
The first comparison returns NULL, and the bug (feature) is that oracle does not stop the check, although it is already known that NULL is not equal to TRUE.
But since NULL is not FALSE, it checks the second condition, etc.
But in the end, after all the checks, if it does not meet FALSE, it will understand that NULL AND TRUE AND TRUE is not TRUE and will not execute the THEN block

```
with data as(
select null oopname, 'fgdfhdfhdf' paramvalue from dual
)
select 
  case 
    when  decode(oopname,'PAY_OPERDATE',1,0) = 1
      and length(paramvalue)=10 
      and to_number(substr(paramvalue,4,2))<=12 
    then paramvalue 
  end
from data
```

Comment: This is not a bug. This appears to be a misconception about how expressions are evaluated. Just because you have written the expressions `a and b and c` does not mean that the SQL Engine will evaluate `a` and then `b` and then `c` and short-circuit the evaluation if any condition is not true and not evaluate the rest. That may happen in other languages but they are different languages. The SQL engine does not guarantee any order of execution and will pick the most advantageous order based on its statistics and the cost-based optimiser so `c` could be evaluated first.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR`:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN oopname = 'PAY_OPERDATE' 
       AND  length(paramvalue)=10 
       AND  to_number(substr(paramvalue,4,2) DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)<=12 
       THEN paramvalue 
       END AS paramvalue
FROM   data
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sX1GGkdd)

---

> Why does the following code not work in SQL?

You have:

```sql
CASE WHEN simple_expression THEN result END
```

Where `simple_expression` is in the form `expr1 AND expr2 AND expr3`. The issue is not with the `CASE` expression but with the evaluation of the sub-expression nested within it. The SQL engine can evaluate `expr1`, `expr2` and `expr3` in any order and may choose to evaluate the last expression first if it decides, based on the statistics/cost-based optimiser, that it most advantageous to do so. The order in which you write the expressions is not taken into account.

In contrast, if you had:

```sql
CASE
WHEN expr1 THEN result1
WHEN expr2 THEN result2
WHEN expr3 THEN result3
END
```

Then Oracle's SQL engine will evaluate the cases in order and will not evaluate later expressions (or results) if a match is found for an earlier case.

Answer (score 1):

Split the CASE WHEN into two or more

```
with data as(
select null oopname, 'fgdfhdfhdf' paramvalue from dual
)
select 
  case 
    when  oopname = 'PAY_OPERDATE'  then
  
      CASE WHEN length(paramvalue)=10 
      and to_number(substr(paramvalue,4,2))<=12 
    then paramvalue 
  ELSE NULL END 
  ELSE NULL
  end
from data
```

| CASEWHENOOPNAME='PAY_OPERDATE'THENCASEWHENLENGTH(PARAMVALUE)=10ANDTO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(PARAMVALUE,4,2))<=12THENPARAMVALUEELSENULLENDELSENULLEND |
| --- |
| *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kefHW9BS)